# how to override the swipe gesture in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

all, I'm a newbie on ios development.

I want to implement a right swipe gesture to UIWebView, which should have the action specified by me. However, the when the web page is too large that causes the UIWebView has a scroll bar, then my custom left swipe gesture doesn't work at all. In this case, when I swipe right, then the scroll bar will move, instead of triggering my specified action. Is there any way to disable the scroll bar moving action when I swipe right?

Hope my question is clear to you ...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either add a transparent view over the webview, or make a subclass of UIWebView and override the touchmethods.

Comment: thanks for your reply. do you have any pointer to web pages on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the whole scroll in the `UIWebView` like this

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[webView subviews] lastObject];

if([scroll isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
{
    scroll = (UIScrollView*)scroll;
    [scroll setScrollEnabled:NO];
}
```